# Unable to run simple task in the background of docker/flask/celery/redis/beat app

Tags: docker, flask, redis, celery

I have a flask/docker/celery/reddis/beat app.

I am trying to add the task "delete_conversations_and_child_messages_after_task" so that it runs every minute.

these are the important files::

APP.PY

```
# app.py  

from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager


from services.celery.celery_config import init_celery
from services.celery.celery_instance import celery  # do dont remove
from celery.schedules import crontab



nltk.download('punkt')


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 1000 * 1024 * 1024  # 1000 MB  note: first number is the number of MB to allow



# Celery configurations
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
app.config['result_backend'] = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
app.config['CELERYD_TASK_LOG_SUCCESS'] = False
app.config['CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE'] = {
    'delete_old_conversations': {
        'task': 'services.celery.tasks.delete_conversations_and_child_messages_after_.delete_conversations_and_child_messages_after_task',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),  # runs every minute
    },
}
# Initialize Celery using the provided function
init_celery(app)
```

DOCKER-COMPOSE.YML

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        ENVIRONMENT: local  
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    
    environment:
      FLASK_ENV: development
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1
    env_file:
      - .env  

    depends_on:
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/app

  worker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        ENVIRONMENT: local

    command: celery -A app.celery worker --loglevel=info
    environment:
      FLASK_ENV: development
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1
    env_file:
      - .env

    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"

  beat:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
        args:
            ENVIRONMENT: local
    command: celery -A app.celery beat --loglevel=info
    environment:
        FLASK_ENV: development
        PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1
    env_file:
        - .env
    depends_on:
        - redis
```

CELERY_CONFIG.PY

```
# services.celery.celery_config.py

from services.celery.celery_instance import celery
def init_celery(app):
    celery.conf.broker_url = app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL']
    celery.conf.update(app.config)


# services.celery.celery_instance.py

from celery import Celery

celery = Celery()
```

REDIS:

```
import redis

# Initialize Redis
def get_redis_connection():
    return redis.StrictRedis(host='redis', port=6379, db=0)
```

DELETE_CONVERSATIONS_AND_CHILD_MESSAGES_AFTER.PY

```
# services.celery.tasks.delete_conversations_and_child_messages_after_.py
from services.celery.celery_instance import celery

from services.redis.initialize_redis import get_redis_connection

r = get_redis_connection()

@celery.task(bind=True)
def delete_conversations_and_child_messages_after_task(self,):
    print("delete_conversations_and_child_messages_after_() TASK!!!!")
```

i ran the following to see the logs:

```
juan@192 docwise-backend % docker-compose logs worker
docwise-backend-worker-1  | [nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to /root/nltk_data...
docwise-backend-worker-1  | [nltk_data]   Unzipping tokenizers/punkt.zip.
docwise-backend-worker-1  | 'FLASK_ENV' is deprecated and will not be used in Flask 2.3. Use 'FLASK_DEBUG' instead.
docwise-backend-worker-1  | [nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to /root/nltk_data...
docwise-backend-worker-1  | [nltk_data]   Package punkt is already up-to-date!
docwise-backend-worker-1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/platforms.py:829: SecurityWarning: You're running the worker with superuser privileges: this is
docwise-backend-worker-1  | absolutely not recommended!
docwise-backend-worker-1  | 
docwise-backend-worker-1  | Please specify a different user using the --uid option.
docwise-backend-worker-1  | 
docwise-backend-worker-1  | User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0
docwise-backend-worker-1  | 
docwise-backend-worker-1  |   warnings.warn(SecurityWarning(ROOT_DISCOURAGED.format(
docwise-backend-worker-1  |  
docwise-backend-worker-1  |  -------------- celery@35323693fc1a v5.3.4 (emerald-rush)
docwise-backend-worker-1  | --- ***** ----- 
docwise-backend-worker-1  | -- ******* ---- Linux-6.3.13-linuxkit-aarch64-with-glibc2.31 2023-09-15 18:21:44
docwise-backend-worker-1  | - *** --- * --- 
docwise-backend-worker-1  | - ** ---------- [config]
docwise-backend-worker-1  | - ** ---------- .> app:         __main__:0xffff86062dd0
docwise-backend-worker-1  | - ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://redis:6379/0
docwise-backend-worker-1  | - ** ---------- .> results:     redis://redis:6379/0
docwise-backend-worker-1  | - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
docwise-backend-worker-1  | -- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
docwise-backend-worker-1  | --- ***** ----- 
docwise-backend-worker-1  |  -------------- [queues]
docwise-backend-worker-1  |                 .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
docwise-backend-worker-1  |                 
docwise-backend-worker-1  | 
docwise-backend-worker-1  | [tasks]
docwise-backend-worker-1  |   . services.celery.tasks.delete_conversations_and_child_messages_after_.delete_conversations_and_child_messages_after_task
docwise-backend-worker-1  |   . services.celery.tasks.process_openai_api.process_openai_api
docwise-backend-worker-1  | 
docwise-backend-worker-1  | [2023-09-15 18:21:44,580: WARNING/MainProcess] /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py:507: CPendingDeprecationWarning: The broker_connection_retry configuration setting will no longer determine
docwise-backend-worker-1  | whether broker connection retries are made during startup in Celery 6.0 and above.
docwise-backend-worker-1  | If you wish to retain the existing behavior for retrying connections on startup,
docwise-backend-worker-1  | you should set broker_connection_retry_on_startup to True.
docwise-backend-worker-1  |   warnings.warn(
docwise-backend-worker-1  | 
docwise-backend-worker-1  | [2023-09-15 18:21:44,588: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://redis:6379/0
docwise-backend-worker-1  | [2023-09-15 18:21:44,589: WARNING/MainProcess] /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py:507: CPendingDeprecationWarning: The broker_connection_retry configuration setting will no longer determine
docwise-backend-worker-1  | whether broker connection retries are made during startup in Celery 6.0 and above.
docwise-backend-worker-1  | If you wish to retain the existing behavior for retrying connections on startup,
docwise-backend-worker-1  | you should set broker_connection_retry_on_startup to True.
docwise-backend-worker-1  |   warnings.warn(
docwise-backend-worker-1  | 
docwise-backend-worker-1  | [2023-09-15 18:21:44,596: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
docwise-backend-worker-1  | [2023-09-15 18:21:45,605: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
docwise-backend-worker-1  | [2023-09-15 18:21:45,621: INFO/MainProcess] celery@35323693fc1a ready.
juan@192 docwise-backend % docker-compose logs beat
docwise-backend-beat-1  | [nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to /root/nltk_data...
docwise-backend-beat-1  | [nltk_data]   Unzipping tokenizers/punkt.zip.
docwise-backend-beat-1  | 'FLASK_ENV' is deprecated and will not be used in Flask 2.3. Use 'FLASK_DEBUG' instead.
docwise-backend-beat-1  | [nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to /root/nltk_data...
docwise-backend-beat-1  | [nltk_data]   Package punkt is already up-to-date!
docwise-backend-beat-1  | celery beat v5.3.4 (emerald-rush) is starting.
docwise-backend-beat-1  | __    -    ... __   -        _
docwise-backend-beat-1  | LocalTime -> 2023-09-15 18:21:44
docwise-backend-beat-1  | Configuration ->
docwise-backend-beat-1  |     . broker -> redis://redis:6379/0
docwise-backend-beat-1  |     . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
docwise-backend-beat-1  |     . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
docwise-backend-beat-1  |     . db -> celerybeat-schedule
docwise-backend-beat-1  |     . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
docwise-backend-beat-1  |     . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
docwise-backend-beat-1  | [2023-09-15 18:21:44,036: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
juan@192 docwise-backend %
```

if i run "docker-compose exec worker celery -A app.celery call services.celery.tasks.delete_conversations_and_child_messages_after_.delete_conversations_and_child_messages_after_task" i can see the print statements that i want to see.

why dont i see the print statement everyminute?

Comment: Looking at the traceback, it seems that the issue is coming from the way you are attempting to connect with Redis in your app. Maybe start by checking there first.

Comment: i was able to fix that . thanks for pointing it out @Undesirable.

Comment: i updated the question.
If i run the task manually i can see the print statements.

i dont see the print statements everyminute though

Answer (score 0):

I used the wrong property.
this is what it should have been::

```
app.config['beat_schedule'] = {
    'delete_old_conversations': {
        'task': 'services.celery.tasks.delete_conversations_and_child_messages_after_.delete_conversations_and_child_messages_after_task',
        # 'schedule': crontab(hour=0, minute=0),  # runs daily at midnight
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),  # runs every minute
    },
}
```